# OpenSSH login without password prompt by user that present in both systems /etc/shadow file

Tags: authentication, ssh, passwords, shadow, openssh

Is it possible to login from local to remote Linux PC SSH by (not root) user that presents in both systems without password input? I mean - use /etc/shadow on both points as password for login to remote SSH with same user credentials (login and password identical on both systems).

Main point - is not use key based authentication and use encrypted password (SHA-512) to login on remote SSH.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a system to login into a remote system with no password required, you create a new encryption key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Copy the file to the remote:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub user@remote
```

Now when you ssh into the remote, you will no longer be asked for the password.